# MQTT certificate-based authentication in flutter web and mobile

Tags: flutter, mqtt, flutter-web

I am trying to use MQTT in a Flutter project to test the prototype. And I am using custom certificate-based authentication.

I am using [mqtt_client](https://pub.dev/packages/mqtt_client) package.
before connect SecurityContext giving this error in web **Unsupported operation: default SecurityContext getter**

below is my sample code

````
  try {
      SecurityContext securityContext =
          SecurityContext(withTrustedRoots: false);
      securityContext.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(caCertificate);
      securityContext.useCertificateChainBytes(caCertificate);
      securityContext.setClientAuthoritiesBytes(clientCertificate,
          password: String.fromCharCodes(privateKey));
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

    _client = MqttClient('m.test.com', _identifier);
    _client.port = 8883;
    _client.keepAlivePeriod = 20;
    _client.onDisconnected = onDisconnected;
    _client.secure = true;
    //_client.securityContext = securityContext;
    _client.onBadCertificate = ((X509Certificate cert) => false);
    _client.logging(on: true);```
````

Answer (score -1):

this worked for me but I don't understand what (dynamic a) is doing ... perhaps someone can explain it in more detail ?

```
void initializeMQTTClient() async {
    _client = MqttServerClient(_host, _identifier);
    _client.port = 8883; //1883
    _client.keepAlivePeriod = 20;
    _client.onDisconnected = onDisconnected;
    _client.secure = true; // false
    _client.logging(on: true);
    _client.securityContext = SecurityContext.defaultContext;
    // _client.useWebSocket = false;
    /// Add the successful connection callback
    _client.onConnected = onConnected;
    _client.onSubscribed = onSubscribed;
    _client.onBadCertificate = (dynamic a) => true;
```